# Save variables in Python

Tags: python

My question is regarding saving values of variables in Python. More specifically I have two different scripts that calculate the same things with 2 different ways. What I want to do is to compare the values of the variables returned from the two scripts. So I was wondering if I can run the first script, save the values of one of my variables (let say a matrix V) and then run the second script and compare the values for the same variable as they are calculated by the second script.

- List item

Comment: Great! Now go ahead and implement it, if you face difficulties, then post your code with errors.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to do this? What have you tried?

Comment: I think you may be looking for a structured file format such as `yaml` or `json` that supports save/load of python variables?

Comment: Why don't you just import both of the scripts? Then you don't need to save anything.

Comment: @fnokke The question strikes me as much more low-tech, perhaps as simple as comparing the output of two different functions. As it is, the question isn't very clear.

Comment: Go take a look at the `pickle` module

Answer (score 3):

Like @claymore said in the comments, this can be done with pickle. You store the variable you want from each into a pickle and then grab the pickle objects from the comparison script.

An example is below

**script_a.py**

```
# Save a dictionary into a pickle file.
import pickle

def funca():
    favorite_color = { "lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red" }
    with open("a.pickle","wb") as f:
        pickle.dump( favorite_color, f)

funca()
```

**script_b.py**

```
# Save a dictionary into a pickle file.
import pickle

def funcb():
    favorite_color = { "lion": "blue", "kitty": "orange" }
    with open("b.pickle","wb") as f:
        pickle.dump( favorite_color, f)

funcb()
```

**compare.py**

```
# Load the dictionary back from the pickle file.
import pickle
import os

os.system("python script_a.py")
os.system("python script_b.py")

a_fav = pickle.load(open( "a.pickle", "rb" ))
b_fav = pickle.load(open( "b.pickle", "rb" ))

print "script 1 had favorite = ", a_fav
print "script 2 had favorite = ", b_fav
```

source: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle